# Templates creation : HTML template VS From existing template?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I have a question concerning templates creation. Our client wants to be able to create his own emails. He doesn't code. 
He should provide the HTML of the Header and Footer created by his webagency.

What is the best way to create templates between these 2 options:
- Asking the agency to creating the whole template in HTML with header and footer, and provide in the HTML code wherever needed, "empty areas" with the following code :

```
<div data-type="slot" data-key="nx5qevsfxy" data-allowed-blocks="" data-max-blocks="" data-label="Drop blocks or content here"></div>
```

so that the client can drag and drop any SFMC blocks he needs to create his emails.

- or creating a template with "Create template from existing template" and choose the "Blank page" and then, add HTML blocks for Header and footer, and save it as a Template, so that the client can drag and drop any SFMC blocks he needs to create his emails.

I was wondering if one option was better comparing to the other(s) to create templates to reuse in standard, knowing that the header and footer should be HTML developed by the agency. Is there an option that would be more adapted (maybe to get the best display on most devices)?

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of the emails (with or without dynamic content, personalization, if it uses the standard font, how complex is the layout, if there is a logic behind that may requires to use AMPScript...) and if one day your client will need to assume the email creation task or not.

Without having that much details, I would try to follow the approach of replicating the email templates and the content using the blocks and layouts of Marketing Cloud, so you can minimize the probability of having to code and the depending from an external agency to maintain the templates.

For the content of the email itself, I suggest trying to use also the standard blocks of Marketing Cloud, that can be easily built without coding and these are reusable on different emails.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually, they may need personalization and dynamic content. But I guess it is possible to use dynamic content and ampscript even on emails that mixes HTML blocks and "standard" SFMC blocks ?

Comment: Yes, you can follow both approaches. You can mix both AMPScript and HTML code or use standard dynamic content blocks within the HTML paste template.

Comment: and we can also mix both AMPScript and HTML code or use standard dynamic content blocks within a "standard" SFMC template ?

Comment: yes, all the templates and standard blocks in MArketing Cloud includes the HTML editor tab where you can add the AMPScript or extra HTML code